# What is the difference between "microproteome" and "peptidome"?

Tags: proteins, terminology, proteomics

I know that "peptide" is sometimes used to refer to both microproteins and short peptides derived from longer proteins (post-translational), but I do not know whether this extends to "peptidome" versus "microproteome"?